# Why I get undefined if value is present in constructor?

Tags: angular, angular8

There is service with variable `findbyobjectidlatest$`:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class ConstructionObjectsDataService {    
  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private parametersService: ParametersService
  ) {
    console.log(this.parametersService.findbyobjectidlatestFilter);
  }

    findbyobjectidlatest$ = this.httpClient.get<any>(
    `${environment.apiUrl}/${this.URL_PATH}/findbyobjectidlatest?objectid=${this.parametersService.findbyobjectidlatestFilter.parameters.objectid}`
  );

}
```

Why value is presented in constructor:`console.log(this.parametersService.findbyobjectidlatestFilter);` as:

```
{ parameters: {objectid: "08438F2E01384371BFED6E282950C054"}}
```

But it is undefined in line in http client request:

```
${this.parametersService.findbyobjectidlatestFilter.parameters.objectid}
```

If move all varaible in constructor I can get object in constructor:

[image: 1]

But why I get still undefined:

```
console.log(this.parametersService.findbyobjectidlatestFilter.parameters.objectid);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

member findbyobjectidlatest$ initialized before constructor

you can do as follow

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class ConstructionObjectsDataService {    

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private parametersService: ParametersService
  ) {
  }

  getQuery() {
    const vals = this.parametersService.findbyobjectidlatestFilter;
    console.log(vals);
    const parameters = vals.parameters;
    console.log(parameters);
    const objectid = parameters.objectid;
    console.log(objectid);

    const apiUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}`;
    const URL_PATH = `${this.URL_PATH}`;
    const objectid = `/findbyobjectidlatest?objectid=${objectid}`;
    const url = apiUrl + URL_PATH + objectid ;
    console.log(apiUrl, URL_PATH, objectid);

    return this.httpClient.get<any>(url);
  }
}
```

in case parametersService or other parameters is not ready at the moment of constructor call you can get query from method

Comment: The answer looks legit, did you tried it out @AliceMessis?

Comment: Yes, I have tried your answer, it is still undefined

Comment: @AliceMessis is this.URL_PATH defined? you can separate string into const or into several const for debug and separate sub objects from this.parametersService.findbyobjectidlatestFilter

Comment: Yes, I did that it is still undefined, because in another component I fill  `this.parametersService.findbyobjectidlatestFilter` and it calls only one time constructor, where is this.findbyobjectidlatest$ = http.get();

Comment: So, first is created constructor: `    public constructionObjectsDataService: ConstructionObjectsDataService` then I fill data: ` this.parametersService.findbyobjectidlatestFilter.parameters.objectid = objid;` and then I call observer

Comment: @AliceMessis in such case you can make a method to return query after parameters will be ready